# Psychiatry and sufism

Tags: sufism

I'm looking for resources (books or web articles) on how the teachings of Sufism and mysticism in Islam are used to heal the psychiatric disorders of modern known psychiatry.

I'm looking for references of some successfully used methods to heal mental illnesses using Islamic Sufi mysticism teachings and practice.

-----UPDATE-------

I have some interest in [affective computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affective_computing). but when reading about this discipline i found major flaws in the methodology to deal with human emotions using 'affective computing techniques'. I have a plan to do research on how to understand human emotions using computing but introducing new concepts that doesn't only deal with human body physiological signals to interpret and infer emotions. i want to explore another dimension of human emotions based on The mysterious inner high feelings that are experienced by people practicing Islamic Sufism. as Sufism seem to be very linked to human emotions and understanding how Sufism deal with emotions and spirits we can try modeling this in some scientific or computational method that could benefit humanity.

Comment: Sufism is not part of Islam?! What about Abu hamid Al Ghazali and his great book Ihiya Ulum AL din? is this book not part of islam? what about the great warriors of Islam who were Sufi like Salah Al Din Al Ayyoubi, Cheikh Omar Mokhtar of libiya who was a sufi from the sannusi sufi order and was a great mujahid of Islam against the italian occupation? what about Muhammed al fatih who conquered istanbul and was also a sufi in his education? - frankly your point is baseless and prove you narrow-minded view and your very ignorance in Islam!

Comment: you must try watching this [Dealing with Jinn and possesion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0usGDDlyK7A) Gives a clear picture of official ways in Islam to deal with Jinn and/or PSYCHOLOGICAL DISORDERS. You can also consider knowing about [Artificial Neural Networks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) besides Affective Computing.

Comment: Questions asking for open lists of resources really don't work well under the Stack Exchange model; see relevant meta discussion here: http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/261/22